# ibm bluelist and node js sample code error

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, sqlcipher, ibm-mobile-services

using ibm bluemix blulist application : https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-android-bluelist?cm_mc_uid=44237229817214706405928&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1470653588

getting error in android studio :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Darshan\Downloads\bms-samples-android-bluelist-master\bluelist\app\src\main\jniLibs\sqlcipher.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't followed the steps in the readme under [Enabling Encryption](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-android-bluelist#enabling-encryption) correctly. Please ensure you have downloaded the appropriate files and added them to the `app\src\main\jniLibs` directory if you'd like to enable encryption.

Please keep in mind that this sample is no longer supported. If you continue to have issues, try out some of our fully supported [simple Android samples](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=samples-android).